# Tikz, caption is missing with negative axis

Tags: tikz-pgf, captions, axis

the first works while the second not. I think the issue comes from the fact that in the second the axis only have negative values (the rest being perfectly equals). Can anyone help me please?

Here is the code:

```
\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7]
\begin{axis}[
   axis lines = center,
    xlabel = {$x$},
    ylabel = {$y$},
    height=10cm, width=10cm, grid=major,grid style={dashed, gray!30},
    xmin=-6, xmax=6, ymin=-1, ymax=100
    ]%,xtick={1,...,10},ytick={50,100,...,200}]
    \addplot[draw=blue,domain=-9:9]{3*2^x};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{$f(x)=3 \cdot 2^x$} 
\end{figure}


\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7]
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines = center,
    xlabel = {$x$},
    ylabel = {$y$},
    height=10cm, width=10cm, grid=major,grid style={dashed, gray!30},
    xmin=-6, xmax=6, ymin=**-100**, ymax=**1**
    ]%,xtick={1,...,10},ytick={50,100,...,200}]
    \addplot[draw=blue,domain=-9:9]{-3*(1/2)^x};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{$f(x)=(-3) \cdot \big( \frac{1}{2} \big)^x$}
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the figure is very tall, as a frame around can reveal:

```
\begin{figure}
\fbox{
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7]
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines = center,
    xlabel = {$x$},
    ylabel = {$y$},
    height=10cm, width=10cm, grid=major,grid style={dashed, gray!30},
    xmin=-6, xmax=6, ymin=-100, ymax=0
    ]%,xtick={1,...,10},ytick={50,100,...,200}]
    \addplot[draw=blue,domain=-9:9]{-3*(1/2)^x};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\caption{$f(x)=(-3) \cdot \big( \frac{1}{2} \big)^x$}
\end{figure}
```

Which produces:

[image: Result]

The problem is apparently the domain `-9:9`. The value `x=-9` produces a very large negative value for `y`, which causes the bad bounding box. This is probably a bug, but it can be easily circunvented by using `-6:6` as domain (coinciding with `xmin:xmax`):

```
\begin{figure}
\fbox{
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7]
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines = center,
    xlabel = {$x$},
    ylabel = {$y$},
    height=10cm, width=10cm, grid=major,grid style={dashed, gray!30},
    xmin=-6, xmax=6, ymin=-100, ymax=0
    ]%,xtick={1,...,10},ytick={50,100,...,200}]
    \addplot[draw=blue,domain=-6:6]{-3*(1/2)^x};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\caption{$f(x)=(-3) \cdot \big( \frac{1}{2} \big)^x$}
\end{figure}
```

[image: Result]